# Angular route doesn't work on first click of the button

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a list and edit views in my angular app. Experiencing a peculiar behaviour, on click of save button on edit form a save confirmation alert is shown to the users with OK button. Users are expected to navigate back to list view on click of this OK button. However when the users first time click the OK button on confirmation alert nothing happens. The alert dismisses but users are not navigated to list view. When the click save again and then OK on confirmation it works as expected. The user is taken back to list view.

Strangely this issue only persists in non production environments. Using HashLocationStrategy. Suggestions, pointers appreciated

Thanks

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

<button (click)="save()" class="button primary-button ">Save</button>

constructor(
    private _location: Location
  ) {

  }

public save(): void {
...
...
  this.rxs(this.myService.submitFor({
        var1, var2, var3, var4
      }).subscribe(
        (res: AjaxResponse<myModel>) => this.OnAfterSave(res, 'save'),
        err => this.OnSaveFailed(err)
      ));

}

private OnAfterSave(response: AjaxResponse<myModel>, type: string) {
    this.messageSvc.Alert(
      'Title',
      response.isError ? 'Error ! ' + response.errorMessage : 'Saved successfully',
      '',
      response.isError ? null : () => {
        this.showAll = false;
        this._location.back();
      });
  }
```

Comment: share the code, or make a demo on stackblitz for us to try

Comment: Can you please share the stackblitz for the same?

Comment: added code in the post above. thanks

Comment: Are you sure your callback function is being executed first time?

Comment: yes it is called first time. the alert dismisses but doesn't navigate back to list view